# Conditional expectation of a squared random variable

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I wanted to ask how to work with a conditional expectation of a squared random variable.

For instance I want to find E[Y^2|X].

The information I have given is: Y|X,Z is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1+Z and X and Z are both normally distributed.

I tried to apply the law of iterated expectations such that I have E[Y^2|X]=E[E[Y^2|X,Z]|Z] but I don't know how to solve this. For simple Y I have no problems, but I don't know how to work with Y^2.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y|X, Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1+Z)$ hence $Var[Y|X, Z] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2|X, Z] = 1+Z$.
By law of iterated expectation, $\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X, Z]|X] = 1+\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$

Comment: thank you so much !